# Can I share iBooks with another device that is authorized for the purchasing account?

Tags: itunes, sharing, drm, books

Is there a way to share iBooks with a device without connecting it to the machine running iTunes with the purchasing account?

I know that it is possible to download iBooks to a device that uses a different Store account by connecting the device to the machine machine running iTunes with the purchasing account; but is it possible to do so with a device that syncs to iTunes on a different machine (using a different account)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iBooks, like all items bought in the iTunes store, can be shared across different iTunes libraries via [iTunes Home Sharing](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3819). As Apple states:

> Home Sharing in iTunes is designed to let you easily share your iTunes media libraries between up to five computers in your household.

All libraries setup for sharing with the same ID can import purchases made with that ID, independently of the ID they normally use for purchases in the iTunes store. See [Apple Home Sharing Support](http://www.apple.com/support/homesharing/) for details on requirements, setup procedure etc.